# I want to enter an int value into a text box to get a string in a label

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, label

If i enter an int value into the textbox i want to get a different value based on that choice into a label. If i click the button based on the user choice "2" i get the relevant text for that choice
For example - If user enters 2, 3, 4, 5 the numbers will bring up the relevant cases

> If i enter "2" this text will show on the label A (1,2,3) r (3,2);
>   If i enter "3" this text will show on the label A (1,2,3), b(4,5,6), r (3,2);
>   etc..

```
private void btAddElements_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Elements;

        Elements = Convert.ToString(txtbElements.Text);

        if (txtbElements.Text = 2) { 

        lblElements.Text = string.Format ("A = 1,2,3 ");

    };
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @juharr i want to give users a choice of options. if a user enters "2" then the information related to the selection "2" is displayed on a label

Comment: That's not a question, that's a statement.  What part of that are you specifically having problems with?

Comment: @juharr adding different values to a label based on users input into a textbox

Comment: You could create a `Dictionary<string,string>`, with all the possible inputs as the keys with the desired labels as the values.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Switch. Check out the third/fourth examples.

[switch (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Get the value of the textbox and then test value for each case.

```
string Elements = Convert.ToString(txtbElements.Text);

    switch (Elements)
    {
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
            lblElements.Text = string.Format ("A = 1,2,3 ");
            break;
        case "4":
            Console.WriteLine("Case 4");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Elements is a `string` value, not an `integer` value.You are using `integer` value in `case` statement.

Comment: You can't use two different datatypes in switch case.

Comment: Yep apologies for that oversight. Someone had kindly edited my code, it its okay now.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it ->

```
int.Parse(txtbElements.Text)
```

you are right juhar don't know what i was thinkig

Comment: `Text` is already a `string`.  Why would you call `ToString` on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse` method because it does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.And Use `Switch case` statement for displaying the string values.

```
private void btAddElements_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // string Elements="";
         int choice=0;

      bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtbElements.Text.ToString(), out number);
          if (result)         
            {
                 choice=number;
            }       

        switch(choice)
        {

            case 2: 
                lblElements.Text = string.Format ("A = 1,2,3 ");
                 break;

            //other cases.
        }

    }
```